# C++ windows service program called DLL is not working properly

Tags: c++, windows, service

I wrote a websocket server program running on Windows service.According to project needs, a DLL is called. This DLL needs to read my computer shagn a file under my document.However, the windows service program called DLL can succeed, but DLL failed to read the file under my document. When the server is not running as the windows service, DLL can read the files under my document successfully. I'm so depressed, I don't know why.Who can help me.Thank you

Comment: How important is the fact that call goes through a DLL? Re service security, that's been changed (radically, I believe) since the Windows 2000 days, possibly several times. So don't rely on old information you find on the nets: it can easily be stale.

Comment: Calling DLL is necessary,Can you give me a solution?Thank you .

Comment: Necessary perhaps, but is it *relevant* to the problem? Anyway the technical solution lies in the direction of user accounts, impersonation, access control lists, that sort of thing. It's like ~20 years since I did that stuff, so I'm only waiving you on, sort of.

Comment: This DLL is provided by the manufacturer, and many operations are performed through DLL. I don't know if windows services call DLL and Win32 console to call DLL. Why does DLL perform different results?When the DLL starts running, it needs to read a file in my document on the computer

Comment: Perhaps I've been unclear. So here's a concrete action recommendation: try to access one of those files directly from your main service code. I'm pretty sure you'll get the same result, that it fails.

Comment: Why accessing a file from the windows service program main code fails?Could you tell me? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Services by default run under the local system account, not your user account.  My Documents is a per user folder, so the DLL loaded by the service is either looking in the wrong place, does not have permissions, or both.

Comment: Do you know how to solve it?  Thank you

Comment: Answer needs a book on user permissions, ACLs, tokens and impersonation.  So too broad for SO.

Comment: There is a possible shortcut: twenty years ago (or so) there was a utility in the Windows Resource Kit for running an ordinary program as a service.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and reply

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's creating precisely the issue the OP is describing. Linking their DLL into a regular application, run under a regular user account has access to that user's private data, whereas using the DLL from a service (presumably running under one of the default service accounts) will not. The resource kit tool will establish the exact same restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

When several users using the same PC, each regular user have a `My Document` dir, and can't access other user's `My Document`. 
When You run a service, it run by default as **Local System** or **Local Service** which are restrict users, and doesn't have access to your `My Document` dir.

You must think: how the service can choose from all other users in your PC which is the user it should take the file from?

The simple solution is to run the service as your user. You can try it manually by open  the service **Properties** (on services, right click and choose Properties, or double click), choose **Log On** tab, and fill the acount username and password to your username and password.

A real solution is to place the file in a fixed place, like `%LocalAppData%\AppName`, not depending on any user.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and help. I'll try it .Best Regards

Comment: A *real* solution would impersonate the user to gain access to resources owned by that user. Besides, calling Local System a restricted user account is *really* stretching it. After all, it's *The* account to rule them all.

Comment: @IInspectable By restricted I mean not administrator. only administrator have access to private user accounts. sure you can give Local System access to user acount but run the service as this user will do the same trick. It looks a bit rediculus to enforce service to run as **Local Service** and also enforce specific user to be exists, just to take file from it documents folder, when **%LocalAppData%** folder exists for such as things.

Comment: You've got that backwards. The [LocalSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/localsystem-account) account's token includes the `BUILTIN\Administrators`. The DLL presumably cannot read the file, because it is looking in the wrong place, not because it's lacking permissions.

Comment: The LocalSystem account has full unrestricted access to everything on the local machine, hence its name. It just can't find user-specific paths like `Documents` without access to a user token, such as from impersonating a user, or extracting the logged in user of a given session, etc. That is why APIs like `SHGetFolderPath()` and `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` take an optional user token as input, specifically for admins and services that need access to per-user paths.